# How can i convert a std::string to UaString?

Tags: c++, string, server, opc

I am still new to OPC UA. My problem: How can i convert a std::string to UaString?
Is it possible at all?

Thank you in advance =)

Comment: did you bother to read some documentation ? It took me more time to write this than to find the answer here : http://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdkcpp/1.5.3/html/classUaString.html

Comment: @user463035818 i have read this doc a few times, there is no info to convert a std::string to UaString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string test = "Hey";
UaString testUA = test.c_str();`

`c_str()` method of `std::string` returns raw `const char* const` of the current string,
and as I have read in the documentation, `UaString` has a constructor with parameter `const char*`.

Comment: it works!! Thank you so much!! I did not consider the way over "char"!