# How to convert opcua string to standard string in c++

Tags: c++, string, opc-ua

can someone tell how to convert `UaString` to `std::string` in c++.

There is already a question which converts `std::string` to `uastring`:
[How can i convert a std::string to UaString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343293/how-can-i-convert-a-stdstring-to-uastring)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try any of the suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

e.g. You have UaString as below:

```
UaString sString("Test String");
```

Then you can make standard string as,

```
std::string myString(sString.toUtf8());
```

Reference:

[UA Server SDK C++](https://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdkcpp/1.4.2/html/classUaString.html)

[C++ String Class](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to use the [`toUtf8`](https://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdkcpp/1.4.2/html/classUaString.html#a83d43472a658bf2683cbead33f4f9a2f) member function which returns a `const char*` that can be used to construct a `std::string`.

```
std::string str(uastring.toUtf8());
```

An alternative if `uastring` may contain null terminators:

```
std::string str(uastring.toUtf8(), uastring.size());
```

Note that `UaString::length()` shouldn't be used in this case since it returns the number of UTF8 characters while `UaString::size()` returns the number of bytes (which may be greater).